# Conditional downcast from 'String' to 'String' always succeeds - Swift Error

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to essentially do an valid check on a String in Swift, however I'm getting an error `Conditional downcast from 'String' to 'String' always succeeds`.

zipCode is created:

```
var zipCode = String()
```

Checking for a valid string at a later time:

```
if let code = zipCode as? String {
    println("valid")
}
```

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `zipCode` is a kind of `String` in every moment, why do you want to downcast it to `String`, if you already know it is _a_ `String`? the compiler has been just intelligent enough to warn you not to do such pointless task. if you want to work optional, that would make sense,  but your OP has not mentioned anything about any optionals.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If `zipCode` can be "unset", then you need to declare it as an optional:

```
var zipCode: String?
```

This syntax (which is known as *optional binding*):

```
if let code = zipCode {
    print("valid")

    // use code here
}
```

is used for checking if an optional variable has a value, or if it is still unset (`nil`).  If `zipCode` is set, then `code` will be a constant of type `String` that you can use to safely access the contents of `zipCode` inside the `if` block.

Comment: Ah okay, I was mixing the syntax for an Optional and a string literal. Thanks.

Comment: `String!` is an implicitly unwrapped optional, you probably meant `String?` ? - And the conditional cast `as? String` it not necessary here and causes a compiler error if the variable is known to be a (optional) string.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R for keeping me honest.

Comment: @MartinR: well an implicitly-unwrapped "optional" is still a kind of optional

Comment: @newacct: Sure, I just found the first version of the answer a bit unclear.